# JQGrid / JSGrid. Add additional rows after the grid has been created (lot of records in the database)

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jqgrid, jsgrid

I have a query which returns a huge set of data (json). This takes far to long to present the grid to the user. So what I want to do is fire the initial query with a filter (say the records of the current year) and let the grid be build.

The grid is presented to the user and he can start working.

Meanwhile I fire a second query (in the background) to get all the other records (everything except the current year).

Now I want to add those records to the already existing grid. Without the user noticing.

Is this possible?

I think JSgrid and JQgrid behave the same but I use JSGrid

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Guriddo jqGrid you can first load small portion of data and then using grid complete event set the datatype to local, load all the data put it into the data parameter and refresh the indexes. The loaded variable is used to prevent repeated loading in case of sorting pagging and etc - i.e the code is executed only once

Bellow the code  [and demo](http://guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/loading_data/background/)

```
    var loaded = false;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            // url to load initially 10 records
            url: 'grid.php',
            datatype: "json",
....

            gridComplete : function() {
                // if the all the data is not loaded 
                if(!loaded)  {
                    // set the datatype to local
                    this.p.datatype='local';
                    var ts = this;
                    $.ajax({
                        "url": "grid.php",
                        "dataType" : "json",
                        // instruct the server to get all the data with the same sortining
                        "data" : { oper: 'grid', page:1, totalrows : -1, sidx : 'CustomerID', sord : 'asc' },
                        success :function( resp ) {
                            // when loaded  simple attach the response data to data array
                            ts.p.data = resp.rows;
                            // refresh the indexes
                            ts.refreshIndex();
                            // mark that the data is loaded in order no to do it again
                            loaded = true;
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, will have a look if JSGrid has something simular. Gives me some kind of direction.

Comment: @hacking_mike Thanks. Glad to help. Suppose there are no big changes in JSGrid

Answer (score 0):

Just set  a delay timer on your function. I am not to sure if user wouldn't notice the changes though. But that's a good starting point i guess.

Here is an example on how to use setTimeout();

This will allow your function to be executed after a certain time. So when an user loads up the table and start working. You will fire the other function(after certain amount of time) that repopulates the table. I am not to sure how your table is populated so not to sure if the execution will be invisible to the user.

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

   setTimeout(function() {
      //your code to be executed after 1 second
    }, delayInMilliseconds);`
```

Comment: Thanks but can you clarify a bit? I do not quit understand your answer. Sorry ;-(

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps. You can find more information on how execute java script function after certain amount of time in the interweb!